# Reading 3 columns of data from .txt into list

Tags: python, list, text-files, multiple-columns

Hello I have a question here. I have the following text file (3 columns and space between). I want to insert each column(tt,ff,ll) into it's own list(time,l,f).

**Text file:**

```
   0.0000000000000000     656.5342434532456082       0.9992059165961109
   1.0001828508431749     656.5342334512754405       1.0009810769697651
   2.0003657016863499     656.5342259805754566       0.9989386155502871
   3.0005485525295246     656.5342339081594218       1.0005032672779635
   4.0007314033726997     656.5342356101768928       0.9996101946453564
   5.0009142542158749     656.5342236489159404       0.9986884414684027
   6.0010971050590491     656.5342474828242985       1.0001061182847479
   7.0012799559022243     656.5342355894648563       1.0003982380731031
   8.0014628067453994     656.5342256832242356       0.9993176599964499
   9.0016456575885737     656.5342218575017341       0.9999117456245585
  10.0018285084317498     656.5342408970133192       1.0000973751521087
  11.0020113592749240     656.5342243211601954       0.9997189612768125
  12.0021942101180983     656.5342320396634932       0.9997487346699927
  13.0023770609612743     656.5342291293554808       0.9991986731183715
```

But I want the following output:

```
time: (0.00,1.00,2.003,4.0007 etc...)
l: (656.53,656.53,656.53,656.53 etc..)
f: (...)
```

**Attempt code:**

```
from numpy import *



def read_file(filename):
   time = [] # list time
   f = [] # ...
   l = [] # ...
   infile = open(filename, "r") # reads file
   for line in infile: # each line in txt file
      numbers = line.split() # removes the " "
      tt = numbers[0] # 1st column?
      ff = numbers[1] # 2nd column?
      ll = numbers[2] # 3rd column?


      time.append(tt) # Inserts 1st column(tt) into list(time) 
      f.append(ff) # ...
      l.append(ll) # ...
      
return time,f,l # return lists

txt1 =read_file("1.txt") # calls function
print txt1 # print return values
```

Comment: I ran the code and its working fine. Whats the exact problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `loadtxt` function of numpy

```
text_array = np.loadtxt('my_file.txt')
time = text_array[:, 0]
l = text_array[:, 1]
f = text_array[:, 2]
```

Comment: This worked very nice. Does this method automatically ignore spaces? How is it different from open(filename, "r")?

Comment: [  0.00000000e+00   1.00018285e+00   2.00036570e+00 ...,   6.10411594e+03
   6.10511612e+03   6.10611630e+03] Got following output :D Thank you

Comment: This method is very useful when you have a simple file where data are stored in a matrix-like shape, because it's really simple to use it. There are several optional arguments to handle headers and so on ; you can check `help(numpy.loadtxt)`

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your code and it works, returning a tuple of lists. If your question is how to turn this tuple of lists into your requested format (which will be very clunky, because of the amount of data), you can just add this to the end, using your `txt1` variable:

(edited to include line breaks)

```
print ("time: ({})\nl: ({})\nf: ({})".format(*[','.join(i) for i in txt1]))
```

This joins each list with commas and uses the unpacking operator (*) to separate them into the three arguments of the `format` function.

I like the other answer that uses `numpy`'s capabilities to process the file. You can also do it this way using built-in functions (note that this returns a list of tuples):

```
def read_file(filename):
  with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    return zip(*[line.split() for line in f])
```

Comment: I just want insert one column into one list. When the indent i get following error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1c4.py", line 23, in <module>
    star1 =read_file("star1_1.10.txt") # calls function
  File "1c4.py", line 13, in read_file
    tt = numbers[0] # 1st column?
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @J.Doe When I ran the snippet (fixing the return indentation, of course) it worked for me. You will have to update your snippet with whatever changes you made if you need help debugging this message--it seems that you modified the `numbers` list has a length of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` statement is currently incorrectly indented. When I corrected that it appears to work.

A simpler way might be

```
def read_file(filename):
    infile = open(filename, "r") # reads file
    rows = [line.split() for line in infile]
    return [r[i] for r in rows for i in range(3)] # return lists
```